# ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module while importing sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda, jupyter

when i import these libraries:

```
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import metrics
```

this error occurs:

[image]

I have installed a lot of sklearn packages put nothing has changed 
I use anaconda and run this code in jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and installed Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019 and it worked!

Note that this involves going into the Visual Studio Installer, selecting "Modify", then selecting "Desktop Development with C++".

I have seen that many users are reporting this issue on Github. You can simply install tensorflow == 2.0.0 and uninstall previous version.